# Ubuntu 16.04 Some program windows open top left and off screen

Tags: unity, bleachbit

My OS has developed a fault where some windows open top left so the title bar with the min, max and close buttons are just off screen.  It doesn't happen with every program.

Firefox, gedit, Tuxguitar and the Onboard keyboard preference window seem to be the main culprits.

LibreOffice, Transmission, Quod Libet are OK.

1. Why does it do this?
2. Is there a fix?

Terry

Answer (score 2):

Even though it was posted 2012, it works for the "bug" that showed up running 16.04 when nothing else worked.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1967258

In short, download CCSM, click on Windows placement, select Smart.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found answer to 2, just recreate a new user as the problem seemed to be corrupted user settings.

Not sure on 1 but I think it might have been because bleachbit was set to delete user settings.  Don't want to check this by experimenting on a working system right now.

Comment: Did you ever find out what settings got corrupted?

Comment: No, didn't play with it.  The great thing about Ubuntu is it needs so little support.  I spend hardly any timing messing around with the operating systems.  Not like the days when I use to use Windows.